# Reading CSV file in resources folder android

Tags: android, opencsv

I am developing an android app in netbeans. I am trying to read CSV file using opencsv. When I put the file in resources folder and try to read it from there, there's an error while building saying invalid resource directory. Where should I store csv file so that it can be read each time the app starts?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

you should put csv file in assets folder ..

```
InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(getAssets()
                        .open("filename.csv"));

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(is);
reader.readLine();
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Some advices;

- Create an object for holding one row data into the csv. ( `Ex: YourSimpleObject` . It provides you  to manage the data easily.)
- Read file row by row and assign to object.  Add the object to list. (Ex: `ArrayList<YourSimpleObject >`)

Code:

```
private void readAndInsert() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {


ArrayList<YourSimpleObject > objList= new ArrayList<YourSimpleObject >();
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
InputStream is = null;

            try {
                is = assetManager.open("questions/question_bank.csv");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BufferedReader reader = null;
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

            String line = "";
            StringTokenizer st = null;
            try {

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                    YourSimpleObject obj= new YourSimpleObject ();
                                    //your attributes
                    obj.setX(st.nextToken());
                    obj.setY(st.nextToken());
                    obj.setZ(st.nextToken());
                    obj.setW(st.nextToken());

                    objList.add(sQuestion);

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }



}
```

Comment: Nice solution. (I like that it doesn't require adding an external library)

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, take a look at [uniVocityParsers](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers). It provides a vast number of ways to parse delimited files. The example bellow loads a Csv File (see in the picture below) from a res/raw folder into a InputStream object, and read it in a colunar manner (a map where key=Column & value=ColumnValues).

[calendario_bolsa.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqRcy.png)

```
//Gets your csv file from res/raw dir and load into a InputStream.
InputStream csvInputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.calendario_bolsa);

//Instantiate a new ColumnProcessor
ColumnProcessor columnProcessor = new ColumnProcessor();

//Define a class that hold the file configuration
CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
parserSettings.setProcessor(columnProcessor);

//Creates a new CsvParser, passing the settings into its construtor:
CsvParser csvParser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);

//Calls parse method, instantiating an InputStreamReader, passing to its constructor the InputStream object
csvParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(csvInputStream));

//Gets the csv data as a Map of Column / column values.
Map<String, List<String>> columnarCsv = columnProcessor.getColumnValuesAsMapOfNames();
```

To add univocityParsers into your Android Project:

```
compile group: 'com.univocity', name: 'univocity-parsers', version: '2.3.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using opencsv:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open(path);
InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
List<String[]> csv = new CSVReader(reader).readAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use this code

```
   try {
                InputStream csvStream = assetManager.open(CSV_PATH);
                InputStreamReader csvStreamReader = new        InputStreamReader(csvStream);
                CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(csvStreamReader);
                String[] line;

                // throw away the header
                csvReader.readNext();

                while ((line = csvReader.readNext()) != null) {
                  questionList.add(line);
                }
              } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

you may download csvreader file from 
http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencsv/files/latest/download

and import in your project